# Blocking specific app notifications access is cleared after app update

Tags: security, notifications, privacy

This behavior is consistent both on real Pixel devices running the latest version of Android 13 and on emulated devices running Android 13 in Android Studio.

1. A specific app, let’s call the app “X”, is allowed notifications access.
2. After enabling the specific app notifications access, open “Settings”, open "Notifications", open "Device & app notifications", select and click the above “X” and in the “X” notifications access detailed settings click on "See all apps".
3. In "See all apps" window, clear the checkbox for a specific app, let’s call this specific app with cleared checkbox “Y”.

The system works as expected. That is, “X” isn’t able to access notifications sent from “Y”.

4. After the above steps let’s suppose the Play Store has an update for the “Y”.
5. The new version of the “Y” is installed.

After installing the new “Y” app version from the store, the user goes back to the “X” detailed notifications access settings and, clicking again on “See all apps”, the check box of the “Y” is now selected, that is the setting has been reverted to the original one forcing the user to clear again the checkbox for the “Y” in the “X” detailed notifications access settings.

This is true for all updated apps that have a cleared checkbox in the “X” notifications access detailed settings.

I don’t see how this can be the expected behavior. If this is the case, the “See all apps” settings in the notification listener detailed settings is useless.

Can you please help in clarifying how the settings in the “See all app” window can be retained when apps are updated?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: For readers, I added a bug report here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/288499758